# Ajax request is sent more than once when button is clicked once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a blur event attached to an input field which is used to send an AJAX request. When I type into this field and click out, from the developer's network tab, I noticed that multiple AJAX requests are fired. Without reloading the page, if I continue to click on the input field and click out (repeating the first action), the AJAX requests increment by 1.
This is my code

```
var accountnumber=$('#account-number');
var submit_btn = $('#submit-btn');
var message = $('#message');  
accountnumber.blur(function () {
    let accountnumber = $(this).val();
    if(accountnumber.length > 0 && accountnumber.length < 10){
        message.html('<span class="mage-error">Your account number must be 15 digits</span>')
        submit_btn.attr('disabled', true);
    }else{
        if(accountnumber.length > 0){
            submit_btn.attr('disabled', true);
            message.html('<img src="'+loader+'" alt="Loading..." /> Verifying account number ');
            // Send ajax request to check for account number
            $.ajax({
                url: siteurl+"uaccount/account/verify",
                data: {account_num:accountnumber},
                method: 'POST'
            }).done(function(data){
                message.html('<span style="color: green">'+data.msg+'</span>');
                submit_btn.removeAttr('disabled');
            }).error(function(err){
                $('#accountnumber').val('');
                message.html('<span style="color: red">'+err.responseText+'</span>');
            })
        }else{
            submit_btn.removeAttr('disabled');
        }
     }
})
```

Comment: This is expected behaviour. Each time you click inside input and click outside, there is one ajax call for that action.

Comment: Is it possible that you are setting the _blur_ event more than once on the input?

Comment: @mgarcia no. Just once.

Comment: @KunsalAjay, could you provide some minimal code in a fiddle that shows the behaviour you are seeing?